# I can't get the cgroup blkio to throttle the iops of processes in a sub-cgroup

Tags: linux, centos7, systemd, cgroup, throttling

I can't get the cgroup blkio to throttle the iops of processes in a sub-cgroup. I am using CentOS 7, 3.10.0-229. I create the cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/user.slice/test1 and do

```
echo 8:32 10 > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/user.slice/test1/blkio.throttle.read_iops_device
```

and likewise for write_iops_device. 8:32 corresponds to HDD at /dev/sdc. I then use stress-ng to read and write to the drive at /srv/hdd-c using

```
cgexec -g blkio:user.slice/test1 stress-ng --temp-path /srv/hdd-c --hdd 15 -t 180
```

and

```
cgexec -g blkio:user.slice/test1 stress-ng --temp-path /srv/hdd-c --readahead 15 -t 180
```

I confirmed that the 30 processes launched are running in the blkio:user.slice/test1 cgroup using `ps eo pid,user,args,cgroup`.

When I do `iostat 5` the number of tps for sdc is 400 to 600, which is the same as when I run them outside the test1 cgroup. I get the same result if I do `echo 8:32 10 > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/user.slice/blkio.throttle.{read|write}_iops_device` and run them in the `user.slice` or `user.slice/test1` cgroup. However, if I throttle at the root of blkio using `echo 8:32 10 > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/blkio.throttle.{read|write}_iops_device`, and then run stress-ng processes, `iostat 5` shows the tps for sdc is 10-11.

Does blkio throttling only work at the root level? The manual pages does not seem to suggest that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue, which I learned from the answer to this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/605642/why-are-cgroups-blkio-serviced-bytes-and-iotop-producing-diverging-results), is that  kernel buffering bypasses the blkio system. Using `fio` with no buffering and directio I was able to throttle the iops to a device to 10 per second using `echo 8:32 10 > /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio/user.slice/blkio.throttle.{read|write}_iops_device`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same result as you, but found that if I used

blkio.throttle.{read|write}_bps_device

that will limit throughput when the device is being used as a filesystem.

Comment: Ken, thanks for the tip. What is the version of the kernel you tested that on?

Comment: AWS Linux - 4.14